# MongoDB update Item in Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need to edit an item at a position(index) in an array without having to add an index to each item.

```js
// The record in the collection
const data = {
    library: 'The book store',
    books: ['bookA', 'bookB', 'bookC']

}
```

I'm looking to only change the item at index `1` within the `books` array

I'm trying the following but it's not working...

```js
return Record.updateOne(
    {
      video_id,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "books[1]": 'Book H'
      },
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      return data;
    }
  );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as long as you need to always update the second element in the array, so you can use the dot notation

your query should be something like that

```
return Record.updateOne(
  { video_id }, // filter part
  {
    $set: { // update part
      "books.1": 'Book H'
    },
  },
  (err, data) => { // call back function
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    return data;
  }
);
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @Mohammed Yousry what happen if I have another nested array instead of a string?

Comment: you can use the same logic, if you want to update the array element at index = 1, but this element is an array, and you want to update this inner array element at index = 2 for example, then the update part will be like this `'books.1.2': 'Book H'`

Comment: If you mean an array of objects, not array of strings, something like that `books: [{ name: 'Book A', author: 'Author 1' }, { name: 'Book B, author: 'Author 2' }, { name: 'Book C', author: 'Author 3' }]`, and you want to update the array element at index = 1, say you want to update the book name, then the query will be `'books.1.name': 'Book H'`, hope it's clear now

Comment: Perfect! thank you @Mohammed Yousry it worked! do you know if is possible to pass the key dynamically or programmatically? for instance I'm trying to pass create the key by interpolating `const key = content.${highlights[0].node}.children.${highlights[0].children}` and then trying to use it as `[key]:value`. but is not recognizing the key

Answer (score 0):

I am demonstrating in pure MongoDB query without unnecessary details so everyone can understand easily.

```js
db.getCollection("libraries").update({/* your filter*/}, {
    $set: {
        "books.1": "Book H"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you @denizkanmaz, but what if I have another nested object inside the array?

Comment: That was not the case in your question :) . And apparently, you've already got the answer in another comment.